# What is the best way to document Prism Modules?

Tags: wpf, uml, prism

I am attempting to document a WPF Prism application made up of multiple modules.  This scenario begs for module documentation, but I'm not sure if there is a formalized way of doing this in UML, either as separate packages or something more generalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, your documentation / design modeling methodology are determined by your company's Software Development Plan or Process.  If your company doesn't have one, you may be well served to first define your design documentation process, independent of what fits best for Prism - particularly if you have applications that have been developed that are not reliant on Prism.  In my experience, Prism, in and of itself, doesn't lend itself necessarily better or worse to any design modeling approach.

That aside, and with respect to UML specifically, Prism modules can usually be logically divided into packages or use cases quite easily.  You've actually already done that when you divided your application into modules in the first place: each module is a loosely coupled, reasonably independent portion of your application.

For example, UI concern modules can often be grouped both according to use case and as separate packages.  Take the [StockTraderRI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) for example: the News, Position, and Watch modules lend themselves quite easily to separate use cases (View News, View Position, Add Stock to Watch, etc.)  Obviously, these can also be represented easily as separate packages, complete with static class diagrams.

With business or data layer modules, such as Infrastructure or service oriented modules, the representation may be almost exclusively as package / class diagrams, with some use case realization diagrams (sequence, etc.) being used to illustrate communication coming from the UI to the services.  Again, with the [StockTraderRI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) application, the Market module and Infrastructure DLL seem to lend themselves to a more static approach.

Again, your approach to documentation and modeling of your application shouldn't be dictated by Prism, as any good modeling language will be able to accommodate Prism.

Comment: Different packages, that's the most sense I've found so far.  Also, like your Mandelbrot set icon. :)